# Limpando mascara de caracteres

Tags: c#

Criei minhas mascara, só que quando eu vou cancelar fica seus caracteres nela.
por exemplo: seu eu coloquei 0000000000, não hora de salvar fica esse número na mascara. Da uma olhada na imagem

meu código de limpar é esse:

```
mtbCPF.Mask = "";
```

meu evento:

```
private void mtbCPF_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (mtbCPF.Mask != null)
    {
        mtbCPF.Mask = "000,000,000-00";
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Jovem, não dá pra entende o que você quer. Tente [edit] sua pergunta e detalhar melhor.

Comment: Cara, está muito confuso isso, por favor nos detalhe qual é o seu problema,quando ocorre o problema, qual é o resultado esperado... Não dá pra saber se vc quer limpar a mascara ou vc quer limpar o campo, se você quer salvar ou se vc quer cancelar, tá dificil...

Answer (score 1):

Todo campo MakedTextbox mostrará sempre a máscara definida.
O que você tem que fazer é limpar o código da máscara usando CLEAR.

Algo como:

```
      mtbCPF.Clear
```